# Getting images to display correctly in a django view

Tags: html, css, django

I have a view inside my django app called flashcard_view which displays some images. There is a small problem with how the images are displayed. The problem is that the overlay images are slightly offset or running of the edges of the images underneath them. This is what I see:

[image: On the last image the overlay is running off of the right side of the image.]
[image: The overlay is running off the sides on the boot image. It looks like the edge of the bicycle image is overlapping the edge of the boots image slightly.]
[image: It looks like there's a little bit of overlap everywhere here.]

Here is the code for this template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
     {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'am_flashcard_template.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flashcard Display</h1>
{{ flashcard }}

{#BEGINNING OF ANKIMASTER TEMPLATE#}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="card">

    <div class='top'>
    </div>

    <div id='sentence-example'>{{flashcard.sentence}}</div>
    <div class='dictionary-form'>{{flashcard.word_dict_form}}</div>
    <div class='brown mid-text'>{{flashcard.ipa}}</div>

    <div class='images-container'>
        <div>
            <img src='{{flashcard.image_1_url}}'/>
            <img class='overlay' src='{{flashcard.image_1_overlay}}'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='{{flashcard.image_2_url}}'/>
            <img class='overlay1' src='{{flashcard.image_2_overlay}}'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='{{flashcard.image_3_url}}'/>
            <img class='overlay2' src='{{flashcard.image_3_overlay}}'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='{{flashcard.image_4_url}}'/>
            <img class='overlay3' src='{{flashcard.image_4_overlay}}'/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src='{{flashcard.image_5_url}}'/>
            <img class='overlay4' src='{{flashcard.image_5_overlay}}'/>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class='part-of-speech mid-text'>{{flashcard.pos}}</div>
    <!--  Class mid-text setting font-size on 30 px -->


    {#<div id='definition'>{{Definition}}</div>#}
    <div id='word-translation'>{{flashcard.word_trans}}</div>
    <button class='btn-translation' id='wordtrans'>WORD TRANSLATION</button>

</div>

<script>
/*
* We can select element by tag $('tagname'), by class name
$('.classname') or by id $('#id').
* If an error occurs while loading an image, such as a broken link, we hide that image with = $(this).hide().
* the .hide() method allows you to hide the selected elements.
* the .show() method allows you to show the selected hidden elements.
*/
$('img').on('error', function () {
    $(this).hide()
})

$('#word-translation').hide()

// The click event occurs when an element is clicked. After clicking the button, we show word-translation and hide the button that was clicked.
$('#wordtrans').click(function() {
    $('#word-translation').show()
    $('#wordtrans').hide()
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the relevant CSS for the images:

```
.images-container{
        margin: 25px 0;
}
.images-container, .image {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}
.images-container img {
    max-height:180px;
}
.images-container div{
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:#fff;
}
.overlay, .overlay1, .overlay2, .overlay3, .overlay4{
    position: absolute;
}
```

The weird thing is that all this code works fine inside my Anki flashcard template. That's where this code was originally used. When the images are displayed in Anki they look slightly different. There is an additional white background that helps align everything.

[image: flashcard inside Anki]

This is the same code but inside Anki it produces different results. How is this possible? What do I have to change to get the white background behind the images. You can see in the above image, the image overlays are forced inside of an image container so it's impossible for them to overlap.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).